# Custom post type category filters WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have been going round and round in circles for the last few hours trying to get the following functionality to work:

I have a custom post type `team`, and a custom taxonomy `team-tax`.

I want a row of buttons at the top which will represent the filters. These need a 'data-filter' attribute set to 'team-tax' - This bit seems to work.

---

Below these filters I have a gallery and each item should show the `team-tax` that it belongs to as a classname - This is where I am struggling as it doesn't return anything.

Many thanks for looking.

Here is the code that I have at the moment:

```
<div class="clearfix">

<button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>

<?php $args=array('orderby' => 'name','taxonomy'=>'team-tax');
  $filters=get_categories($args);
  foreach($filters as $filter){ ?>
    <button class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $filter->gallery_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $filter->name; ?></button>
<?php } ?>



<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'team',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC',
'taxonomy' => 'team-tax'
);
     $query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

    <button class="sort" data-sort="my-order:asc">Ascending Order</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="my-order:desc">Descending Order</button>

    <?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="gallery gallery-border gallery-mixitup">            

            <div class="gallery-item mix <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>" data-my-order="1">

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/dist/images/slider/yachts.jpg">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="gallery-item-text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>There is nothing to see here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue may be with the way that you are attempting to use `get_the_category()`. My recommendation would be to use `wp_get_post_terms()`.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

In short you could replace this line:

```
<div class="gallery-item mix <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>" data-my-order="1">
```

With something like this:

```
<div class="gallery-item mix <?php foreach(( wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'team-tax') ) as $category) { echo $category->slug . ' '; } ?>" data-my-order="1">
```